# java executing selenese scripts via webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement a java program that will execute simple selenese commands with a local webdriver.

is there an API that gets a string such as "clickAndWait" and executes it? The WebDriverCommandProcessor class doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you already seen this?: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: sure, the documentation doens't describe the API much more than the so-brief javadoc

Comment: Actually, I always find more Java examples then PHP examples... :) http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp for waiting for elements to appear (after clicking in your case)

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: exactly what I said, I'm trying to write a program that will execute selenese scripts

Comment: "Selenese" traditionally referred to the HTML table based macro language used by Selenium IDE. Not the webdriver wireline.

Once upon a time Selenium IDE included a feature to convert to skeletal RC/WD library-based code in a few languages... not sure if Java was one of the ones out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebDriver Java API is primarily the methods of `WebDriver` and `WebElement`.  There is no method that takes a command string and executes it.  But the Java API is a wrapper around another protocol, which **is** string-based.  Check out the WebDriver [WebDriver Wire Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol), which is what a WebDriver language binding (client) uses to communicate with a WebDriver browser-driver (server).  The commands do not map directly to "selenese" (the client language of Selenium IDE), but you can build the actions up to make them so.